# Remove div from html with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, dropdown

This is my code. It is in a php file. It doesn't quite do what I want. It hides one option and displays the other, but what I need to do is not just the option to be hidden visually, but not to display at all in the html. Now if you click view source it shows all the divs. I need it when I click one option, the others to disappear from the html and view page source, just the selected to be in there. Any ideas on that?

```
    <select name="type" onchange="showstuff(this.value);"> 
              <option value="code">Code</option> 
              <option value="look">Look</option> 
              <option value="have" selected>Have</option> 
    </select> 

    <div id="have" style="display:block;">1</div>
 <div id="look" style="display:none;">2</div>
    <div id="code" style="display:none;">3</div>

    <script>
    function showstuff(element){ 
        document.getElementById("have").style.display = element=="have"?"block":"none"; 
        document.getElementById("look").style.display = element=="look"?"block":"none";  
            document.getElementById("code").style.display = element=="code"?"block":"none";
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: "View source" will never change. The DOM inspector in your browser will change if you modify the DOM, but the source is what your browser originally received and will not change.

Comment: So there is no way with javascript to display/load in the html just the div I need?

Comment: There is a way to do this @lonesomeday ..... Hold on i'll write it for you

Comment: @the.matrix Yes, but it won't affect "View source".

Comment: Yes it will....

Comment: This is a long shot, but would replacing the text of the options with abase64-encoded sprite image of the text work?

Comment: This is not a `PHP` related question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `div` to put the active option on it.

Something like this

```
<select name="type" onchange="showstuff(this.value);"> 
    <option value="code">Code</option> 
    <option value="look">Look</option> 
    <option value="have" selected>Have</option> 
</select> 

<div id="optionContainer">
</div>

<script>

  //Object with the options. you can access for example have with options['have'] or options.have
    var options = {'have':'<div id="have"><b>1</b></div>',
                   'look':'<div id="have"><b>2</b></div>',
                   'code':'<div id="have"><b>3</b></div>'};

    function showstuff(element){ 
        //Replace the inner HTML of the div optionContainer with the string in the option
        document.getElementById("optionContainer").innerHTML = options[element];
    }

</script>
```

I created this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wx3gk96z/) to see it in action

Comment: Thank you. The thing is that in between that <div id="optionContainer">
</div> I don't have text, but more dives in the different options 1 2 3. Any idea on that?

Comment: Just add the divs in the Object. `'have':'<div id="div1"><div id="div2"></div></div>'`

Comment: For example:     <div id="have"><div id="something"><p>1</p></div></div>
 <div id="look"><div id="something2"><p>2</p></div></div>

Comment: Thank you! I will try that and let you know!

Comment: This is not removing the elements from the page source, it is only obfuscating it.

Comment: @phobia82 What do you think is the best approach, as I see you don't like both answers.

Comment: @driconmax Hit Ctrl+U and you will see that this does not affect the source.

Comment: Both methods in the answers will remove the element from the DOM, but the page source will remain the same, that is the code initially sent to the browser, before any other js modification

Comment: One of the solutions I can see on this is using ajax, don't add any content on load, just call the server with the selected option and display the content accordingly from the response.

Comment: Thx @the.matrix hope it can be useful for you!

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery methods- show(), hide() and remove(). One can use **$("#id").remove()** to remove the html from the rendered page.

https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: This will remove it from the DOM, not from page source

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I voted your answer up. I wish I could mark both answers as accepted.